# Refactor search filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following search method:

```
 def search(search = nil, field_search1,field_search2, field_search3,field_search4,field_search5)
      if search
        where("#{field_search1} LIKE ? OR #{field_search2} LIKE ? OR #{field_search3} LIKE ? OR #{field_search4} LIKE ? OR #{field_search5}LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
      else
        where(nil)
      end
    end
```

It works but it is very ugly. Trying to refactor it so I pass in the field names in the option hash. By doing something like:

```
def search(search= nil, options={})
  options.each do |option|
    #Run the query inside here 
end
```

It be nice if you could loop through the options and then the options that selected run the query that matches that, then when the options hash reaches the end remove the `OR` from the  `LIKE ? OR`

Comment: Is this pure Ruby or are you using some kind of ORM like ActiveRecord, DataMapper, Sequel, etc...

Comment: This is like ActiveRecord yes.

Comment: Have you considered using a fulltext search engine for this?

Comment: Yes it is something that I am considering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def search(search = nil, fields)
  query_string = fields.join(' LIKE :search OR ') + ' LIKE :search'
  (search) ? where(query_string, search: search) : where(nil)
end
```

Though I wouldn't allow the method to be run without a search query. Also, look into full text search: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/58438017998/implementing-multi-table-full-text-search-with-postgres.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you set the local `query_string` variable and then do join the parameter `fields` check if the parameter passed in is LIKE the searched value OR it isn't. Then you run a ternary operation to check if the search value matches the query string or if it is empty. I may have mis-interpreted this slightly. If you could correct me a little in what you have done in this concise version. Thank you

Comment: Hmm..yes, it isn't quite as readable as it could be. If you try `search("example", ['field1', 'field2']).to_sql` you will see the resulting query. The `LIKE :search OR` will be injected between the fields like `field1 LIKE :search OR field2`, which is the reason for `+ ' LIKE :search'` to create `field1 LIKE :search OR field2 LIKE :search`. Then we simply replace `:search` with the search value. The ternary operator is just to address the logic in your original method. As I say, I wouldn't allow the method to run without a search term and remove the search nil check.